# Passing a dynamically generated string from a View to a Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using checkboxes to dynamically create a string of their values, only adding the associated value if the checkbox is selected. The values are comma separated.

Here is a codepen showing how I am doing this:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/mJoybE

HTML:

```
<dl class="dropdown"> 
    <dt>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="hida">▼</span>     
        </a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul class="ul">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Test 1" />PO Number
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="ReturnAuthNumber" />RA Number
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="StatusId" />Status
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="ManufacturerId" />Manufacturer
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
<p class="multiSel"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  function getSelectedValue(id) {
       return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
      var $clicked = $(e.target);
      if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });


  $('.mutliSelect').on('click', function () {
      $('p.multiSel').html(
           $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
           .map(function(idx, elem) {
               return $(elem).parent().text().trim();
           })
           .get().map(function(text) {
               return "<span>" + text + "</span>";
           }).join(', '));
  });
```

Now, I am trying to hide this string in a view using `@Html.Hidden` and pass it to a controller action using a form.

So I changed the html of the paragraph to:

```
@Html.Hidden("selectedRows",new { @class="multiSel"})
```

and the JS to:

```
  $('.mutliSelect').on('click', function () {
      $('multiSel').html(
          $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
          .map(function(idx, elem) {
              return $(elem).parent().text().trim();
          }).get().map(function(text) {
              return text;
          }).join(', '));
  });
```

But I am just getting `{ class="multiSel"}` passed to the controller in the string. I know I am missing pieces here, but what would be the best way to adjust this to pass the hidden string to the controller.

Form Submit:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RunQuery","Report"))
{
    <dl class="dropdown"> 
        <dt>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="hida">▼</span>     
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <div class="mutliSelect">
                <ul class="ul">
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" value="Test 1" />PO Number
                      </li>
                      <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" value="ReturnAuthNumber" />RA Number
                      </li>
                      <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" value="StatusId" />Status
                      </li>
                      <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" value="ManufacturerId" />Manufacturer
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </dd>
      </dl>

      @Html.Hidden("selectedRows",null,new { @class="multiSel"})
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGo">Go</button>
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RunQuery(string selectedRows)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `htmlAttribute` as input value consider this:

```
@Html.Hidden("selectedRows",null,new { @class="multiSel"})
```

instead of

```
@Html.Hidden("selectedRows",new { @class="multiSel"})
```

And you need to change your JS code to:

```
$('.mutliSelect').on('click', function () {
    $('#selectedRows').val(
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
            .map(function(idx, elem) {
                return $(elem).parent().text().trim();
            })
           .get().map(function(text) {
               return text;
           }).join(', ')
       );
   });
```

Comment: Okay, fixed that issue, but its passing an empty string to the controller

Comment: Do you want fill this hidden input's value by JS? By the last JS code you posted?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm going for

Comment: Ok then where is your form? you need trigger this code on submit event. could you provide your full view code? please omit irrelevant parts.

Comment: Okay, added review of how I am triggering the submit event

Comment: Check the updated answer. I trusted your JS code and made some small change on it. Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: Awesome, that did it. The only issue is that it is including the new line characters: `"\r\n                                PO Number\r\n, \r\n                                RA Number\r\n, \r\n"`

Comment: In the server side remove them something like this: `selectedRows.Replace("\r\n", "")`

Comment: But I have tested. I received pure sting "PO Number, RA Number". Anyway you could remove them in server side or client side easy stuff.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll do. Thanks for your help.