# How to set a hidden field from a Check box selection in jquery and passing it to the controller action method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to set the Hidden field in jquery for selected checkboxes. A user can select multiple checkboxes. I have multiple checkboxes which I want to save as comma separated value in Database. I am doing this with help of jquery and setting it using hidden field but no luck.

```
<div id="chkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="Course" name="Courses" id="CoursesScience" value="Science">Science<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Course" name="Courses" id="CourseMath" value="Math">Math<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="Course" name="Courses" id="CourseIt" value="IT">IT<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="Course" name="Courses" id="CourseCommerce" value="Commerce">Commerce<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="Course" name="Courses" id="CourseEnglish" value="English">English
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="CoursesSelected" id="CoursesSelected" />
```

In jquery

```
var Values = [];
$('.Course').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        Values.push($(this).val());
    }
    else{
        Values.pop(this);
    }
});
$('#CoursesSelected').val(Values).appendTo('form');
```

This is not working as when I pop the value it pop last instance save in the array but not the one which is being deselected.

1) Also please tell me how I can access the hidden field in a controller.

2) Will this hidden field populate the property Courses in my class.

```
public partial class Register
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Courses { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a dynamically generated string from a View to a Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922620/passing-a-dynamically-generated-string-from-a-view-to-a-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to use jquery or a hidden field. Instead I would use a view model. Create a new class that only contains the information you want to post from your view, e.g:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string[] Courses { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know what your controller action looks like, but it should now be something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  //Map the data posted to the form to your Register class
  var student = new Register();
  student.Name = model.Name;
  student.Class = model.Class;
  student.Gender = model.Gender;
  if (model.Courses != null)
    student.Courses = String.Join(",", model.Courses);

  //Then do whatever you need to do to save the data to the database
}
```

When you post your form, the Courses array should contain an element whose value is the id for each checkbox that has been ticked, e.g. `["CourseMath", "CourseCommerce"]`.

Comment: Changing the model gives error

The entity type <tableName> is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that your `Register` class was a view model, rather than the model of your table. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you please help with how to remove the element from array which is being deselected not the last one???